# JavaFX on iPhone - Laggy ListView scrolling when applying shadow

Tags: css, javafx, scroll, shadow, javafxports

I am developing an app on iOS using JavaFXPorts. I have a Pane that holds a ListView with countries and their flags. I have noticed that ListView scrolling is laggy when I apply the dropshadow effect on the Pane. As you can see from the videos below, without the effect the scrolling is super smooth, whilst applying the effect through CSS, scrolls starts to get laggy. I would like to keep the shadow effect as it makes app more beautiful. So any suggestion is really appreciated.

CSS Code I am using is:

```
-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
```

[Video: Scrolling without shadow effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IR6N57gAIis&feature=youtu.be)

[Video: Scrolling with shadw effect (Laggy)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAvZbLstADU&feature=youtu.be)

Please note that this is on iPhone 6 running. On iPhone 5 results are much worse.

Comment: Effects on mobile can impact negatively on performance, so the advice is to avoid them as possible. I guess you are already using cache technics for the images. Did you have a look at the [50 States](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/) sample?

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes I've seen that some time ago. I was about to try out the charmlistview cause of the laggy scrolling but accidentally i found out that is the shadow effect producing the problem. Do you think that replacing listview with the charm one could possibly fix the problem with the shadow effect. Cause as far as i concern the problem is not the listview itself but the effect on the outter pane

Comment: As I said, effects are bad for performance, no matter which control you use, but there are a few experimental options that will work better with CharmListView. Again, consider other alternatives to effects (maybe modifying externally the images?)

Comment: @JoséPereda Well yes, I have used that by applying the shadow on the flag image itself. But in the aforementioned case we talk about shadow on a panel and not an image. I am surprised to be honest why it does not scroll smoothly though, as the outer pane remains static and only the content in the list view change.

Comment: I haven't checked, but whenever you scroll maybe the pane gets invalidated  (because its content has changed), and is rendered all over again. Can you try adding another container in-between for the listView, this one without effects?

Comment: @JoséPereda currenly i have a GridPane that holds a label, a listview and a button. Do you mean to wrap listview on another pane and apply the effect on Gridpane?

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried, but the idea is to isolate the scrolling from the root pane, so it doesn't get invalidated.

Comment: @JoséPereda I wrapped the ListView into an AnchorPane but it didn't make any difference on the scrolling. It seems that the parent is dependent of its children

Comment: Can you use a StackPane as root for the Pane (with effect) and the GridPane (without effect)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115880/discussion-between-javasuns-and-jose-pereda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding effects, css, transitions, custom controls and other complex stuff that typically works fine on desktop, there could be a big loss in terms of performance when being ported to mobile.

*Effects*

While effects make nodes or panes look fancy, they have the highest negative impact on performance on mobile.

Try to avoid applying them to nodes that change a lot, like cells on ListView, TableView or ComboBox controls.

Also if you apply them to a parent with the referred children (ListView, ...), the parent (and the effect) will be rendered all the time if the children are invalidated (after scrolling, or similar).

If you really need the effect over this parent, try to split parent and children.

Instead of:

```
parent (Pane with effect)
  |-- ListView
```

you can do something like:

```
parent (StackPane without effect)
  |-- Pane (with effect)
  |-- ListView
```

Since the pane won't change much, you can use Cache over it. Typically, the cache strategy works by rendering an image of the node (pane with effect), instead of recreating all over again the node and that effect, so it is a quick win:

```
parent (StackPane without effect)
  |-- Pane (with effect) and with Cache
  |-- ListView
```

On the contrary, don't use cache on nodes that change a lot (like the ListView).

*CSS*

Complex CSS requires long CPU time. Try to simplify it. Even you can remove the whole CSS for a quick test. Then decide what you may or may not use.

Try as well to replace some of the styling by code.

*Animations*

The same goes for animations: Avoid animations, transitions, if possible.

*Number of nodes and custom controls*

The higher the number of nodes, the lower the performance, so try to keep it to a minimum (replacing complex content with images, canvas when possible).

*Switching scenes*

Mobile screens are smaller and it is better having less content on each scene than on desktop. Also it is important avoiding switching stages or scenes. Instead use different nodes and replace them over the same scene.

Gluon Charm uses `View` [nodes](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/latest/#_the_views), and an easy way to switch between different views: `MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("other view name")`.

*Images*

Finally, when using images either downloaded from internet or loaded from a file, cache strategies are a must. Have a look at those provided by Gluon [Charm Down](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/e39ddddeb213381571b07474779d530617c44994/common/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/common/cache/?at=default).

Comment: Splitting parent and children did the work. I followed your suggestion to add another Pane and apply the shadow effect on that instead of applying it directly on ListView. Once upon I turned the caching on to that node everything started to work like a charm. Smooth and fast scrolling:)