# How to smoothly animate an ImageView with effects applied

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I have created a `CollapsablePane` which shows an `EffectImageView` as `collapsableContent`, and a `Node` as `mainContent`. The `EffectImageView` consists of two layered `ImageViews`, the bottom one having an `BoxBlur` effect applied on it.

When there is a `ScrollEvent` on the `mainContent` the `collapsableContent` will be animated accordingly by `setTranslateY`.

With a `BoxBlur` effect applied, the translation of the lower part of the `collapsableContent` is very unsmooth, while it is absolutely smooth without the effect.

Is there a possibility to improve the transition performance?

[image]
[image]

```
public class EffectImageView extends Pane {

    private ImageView      img;
    private ImageView      imgEffect;

    private Rectangle      clipTop;
    private Rectangle      clipBottom;

    private DoubleProperty imageEffectHeight = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private double         effectOffset;

    public EffectImageView() {
        img = createCachedImageView();
        imgEffect = createCachedImageView();

        imgEffect.imageProperty().bind(img.imageProperty());
        imgEffect.fitWidthProperty().bind(img.fitWidthProperty());
        imgEffect.fitHeightProperty().bind(img.fitHeightProperty());

        clipTop = new Rectangle();
        clipTop.widthProperty().bind(img.fitWidthProperty());
        clipTop.heightProperty().bind(img.fitHeightProperty().subtract(imageEffectHeight).subtract(translateYProperty()));

        clipBottom = new Rectangle();
        clipBottom.widthProperty().bind(img.fitWidthProperty());
        clipBottom.heightProperty().bind(imageEffectHeight);
        clipBottom.translateYProperty().bind(heightProperty().subtract(imageEffectHeight).subtract(translateYProperty()));

        img.setClip(clipTop);
        imgEffect.setClip(clipBottom);

        getChildren().addAll(img, imgEffect);
    }

    private ImageView createCachedImageView() {
        ImageView img = new ImageView();
        img.setCache(true);
        img.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
        return img;
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return img.imageProperty();
    }

    public final Image getImage() {
        return img.getImage();
    }

    public final void setImage(Image image) {
        img.setImage(image);
    }

    public void setImageEffect(Effect effect) {
        imgEffect.setEffect(effect);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty imageEffectHeightProperty() {
        return imageEffectHeight;
    }

    public void setEffectOffset(double offset) {
        effectOffset = offset;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();

        img.relocate(-effectOffset, 0);
        imgEffect.relocate(-effectOffset, 0);

        img.setFitWidth(w + effectOffset * 2);
        img.setFitHeight(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we've already discussed that Css effects have great negative impact on performance on mobile (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819513/poor-listview-performance-on-gluon/36821239#36821239) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057747/javafx-on-iphone-laggy-listview-scrolling-when-applying-shadow/38094569#38094569)). Applying effects within transitions is even worse. Maybe play with opacity instead?

Comment: Yes obviously. I have changed the effect from GaussianBlur to BoxBlur with 1 iteration, hoping this could improve the performance, but it made no visible difference. I ended up changing the opacity during the animation, as you suggested, which makes the animation totally smooth again, but doesn't look nearly as good as with effect